# Format ActiveMQ server like hdfs node format?

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there any option or command line available to format (erase all data)ActiveMQ server like hdfs node format?
[image]

I have deleted the all Queues in ActiveMQ but still is has consumer 47% , how  can format all data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Remove the kahadb folder pointed out by your persistence configuration and restart ActiveMQ. It will be recreated on startup if not present.

Longer answer: As long as there is a message or something going on, ActiveMQ will lock transaction log files where that message is. The log files will be cleaned up with some interval when there are no unconsumed messages within them. That might include unconsumed messages in durable subscriptions and other things.

You can also set the broker attribute `deleteAllMessagesOnStartup` in configuration and restart. That can be useful in some situations.